# How to set a window height is maximize in qooxdoo?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I want to set window height is the full size of my parent component but not possible to set the full size of height.Thank in advance.
    The following code is a sample snippet of our requirement.

```
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("First Window");
win.setAllowMaximize(true)
win.setWidth(300);
//We want to set full height window
win.setBackgroundColor("green");

this.getRoot().add(win, {left:20, top:20});
win.open();
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the height depends upon the layout. Using the playground, as it appears you did for this example, the default layout is Canvas, where distances from individual edges can be specified. To accomplish what you're looking for with the Canvas layout, your example would be modified like this:

```
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("First Window");
win.setAllowMaximize(true)
win.setWidth(300);
win.setBackgroundColor("green");

this.getRoot().add(win, {left:20, top:0, bottom:0});
win.open();
```

Alternatively, and likely what you need for your real application, you have a Vertical Box Layout in which to place the window. In that case, you would use the `flex` layout capability to have this widget take up a proportional amount of space in the container (in this case, it'll use the full height of the container):

```
// Use a vertical box layout instead of the default canvas layout
this.getRoot().setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());

// Create a window
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("First Window");
win.setMaxWidth(200);
win.setShowMinimize(false);

// Add the window to the root with flex so that it takes up available space
this.getRoot().add(win, {flex : 1});
win.open();
```

Derrell